# Set classNames of React Transition Group with stage

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm using React Transition Group. I have state `classFade`, and set `classNames` of React Transition Group = `classFade`. I want when I click to next button, `classFade='fadeRight'` and content will fade to the right. When I click to prev button, `classFade='fadeLeft'` and content will fade to the left. But react transition group takes the previous value, not the value after I pass it on. For example, when I clicked Next Button, it received my original `classFade` empty value, not `'fadeRight'`, only when click the next button again, will it succeed.

My stage:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(
    { id: uuid(), text: 'Buy eggs', classFade: '' }
  );
```

React Transition Group:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  <CSSTransition
    key={items.id}
    timeout={500}
    classNames={items.classFade}
  >
    {items.text}
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

Example when click next button:

```
    setItems({
      id: uuid(),
      text,
      classFade: 'fadeRight',
    });
```

You can check full code and run demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/transitiongroup-component-8x520

Answer (score 1):

My problem resolved in https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/182. They should be add this to docs -.-

```
//This returns a childFactory to provide to TransitionGroup
const childFactoryCreator = (classNames) => (
  (child) => (
    React.cloneElement(child, {
      classNames
    })
  )
);

<TransitionGroup
  childFactory={childFactoryCreator(condition ? "anim1" : "anim2)}
>
  <CSSTransition
     key={key}
     classNames={condition ? "anim1" : "anim2"}
  >
     //Item that gets transitioned goes here
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```